# Beginner issues with DTD references

Tags: xml, dtd

Good afternoon, I'm still fairly new to XMl and DTD's but I'm having fun at the same time. I have a simple assignment I've named "contacts" but I'm having a rough time getting a DTD to validate. I'm missing some stuff of course and was hoping for some hints or a bit of help. Code is below and errors are below the code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Contacts [
<!ELEMENT Contacts (XYZ, ABC, WIZ)>
<!ELEMENT XYZ (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT ABC (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT WIZ (#PCDATA)>
]>
<Contacts>
<XYZ>
"XYZ Inc.",
    "Jones","Barnaby"
    "bjones@xyz.com"
    "Owner-Operator"
    "402-410-2314"
    "8923 Holmes St"
    "Omaha","NE","68222","USA"
    "<div>Prospect</div>"
    "Business"
</XYZ>

<ABC>
"ABC International"
    "Magnum","Thomas"
    "tmagnum@abcint.biz"
    "Owner-Operator"
    "402-310-2222"
    "402-571-2893"
    "3204 Plains Ave"
    "Papillion","NE","68103","USA"
    "<div>Vendor</div>"
    "Business"
</ABC>

<Wiz>"Wiz Kids"
    "Plum","Steve"
    "steve@wizkids.com"
    "Sales Rep"
    "402-555-2325"
    "402-516-2038"
    "402-333-2428"
    "1234 Main St"
    "Belluvue","NE","68201","USA
    #http://wizkids.com#
    <div>Vendor</div>"
</Wiz>
</Contacts>
```

Errors:

1. Element type "div" must be declared
2. Unexpected element "div". The content of the parent element type must match (#PCDATA).
3. Element type "div" must be declared
4. Unexpected element "div". The content of the parent element type must match (#PCDATA).
5. Element type "Wiz" must be declared
6. Element type "div" must be declared
7. Unexpected element "Wiz". The content of the parent element type must match (XYZ,ABC,WIZ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either wrap contents in the xml with CDATA like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE Contacts [
<!ELEMENT Contacts (XYZ)>
<!ELEMENT XYZ (#PCDATA)>
]>
<Contacts>
<XYZ>
<![CDATA["XYZ Inc.",
    "Jones","Barnaby"
    "bjones@xyz.com"
    "Owner-Operator"
    "402-410-2314"
    "8923 Holmes St"
    "Omaha","NE","68222","USA"
    "<div>Prospect</div>"
    "Business"]]>
</XYZ>
</Contacts>
```

Or add div to the element definitions:

```
<!ELEMENT XYZ (#PCDATA|div)>
```

Or define "<" and ">" entities in the DTD and use them instead of actual "<" and ">" in the content:

```
<!ENTITY lt "<">
<!ENTITY gt ">">
<XYZ>
&lt;Prospect&gt;
</XYZ>
```

Keep in mind that XML tags are case sensitive, so either define element Wiz, or call it WIZ in the content.

Also, check out this tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/dtd/default.asp

Comment: That actually helps, however, when I added the "<![CDATA[<div>Vendor</div>]]>"
-it errors and says "The markup declarations contained or pointed to by the document type declaration must be well-formed.

     <!DOCTYPE Contacts [
     <!ELEMENT Contacts (XYZ, ABC, WIZ)>
     <!ELEMENT XYZ (#PCDATA)>
     <!ELEMENT ABC (#PCDATA)>
     <!ELEMENT WIZ (#PCDATA)>
     <![CDATA[<div>Vendor</div>]]>

Comment: You can't declare an element "as CDATA". `<!ELEMENT XYZ (#CDATA)>` is a syntax error. A [CDATA section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA#CDATA_sections_in_XML) is something that you simply use; you don't declare anything in the DTD for that.

Comment: There is no point in declaring the `gt` and `lt` entities in the DTD. They are [predefined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML).